# how to remove special characters from list in python

Tags: python-3.x, list

i have a list like

```
['hold',  'summit',  'septemb',  '8',  '9',  '.',  "'s",  'nancy-amelia',   'sydney',  '.',  'energy',  ',']
```

I want to remove all integers,  'dot' , quotes in "s", 'Comma', 'double quote' from such list in one go Or I want to only keep the string entries only i.e hold, summit etc. in the list and remove all other things

Thank in advance

Comment: What do you mean quotes in `"`?

Comment: If you see the 7th element i.e ''s'. I want to replace it with s only

Comment: it's hard to tell exactly what is a "special" character here. are the numerics special characters? Can you show exactly what your resulting list should be (not an English description, but the list itself)?

Comment: @RyanHaining in the answers ritesh93 has solved it, in the way I wanted. Please refer his answer. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> lst=['hold',  'summit',  'septemb',  '8',  '9',  '.',  "'s",  'nancy-amelia',   'sydney',  '.',  'energy',  ',']
>>> import re
>>> list(filter(lambda x:x, map(lambda x:re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z]', '', x), lst)))
['hold', 'summit', 'septemb', 's', 'nancyamelia', 'sydney', 'energy']
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you ritesh93, This worked but it has changed all the entries into blank spaces. Still, length of the list is same as before.I want to completely remove them
I am trying list.remove("") which is giving me some NanType of object.

Comment: @ritesh93 Done, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
words = ['qwety', 'dot', 's', '"']

filter_words = ['"', 'dot']

filtered = [word for word in words if word not in filter_words]
```

(In line 3) We use python "list comprehension" with "if condition" in it.
That way you can create new list with values, that will pass through if condition (`if word not in filter_words`).

Comment: Please explain what you did editing your answer, avoid code only. Take a look to : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.